# POJO to JSON with Jackson is too slow

Tags: java, json, rest, jackson

I'm sending quite a lot of complex java objects to the client through jackson with rest but it takes around 6 seconds to write the objects as JSON which is too long ! I have around 200 objects which are structured like this :

```
public class LotListMV implements Serializable {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = -1296813516060999040L;

   Map<String, GroupingMissionMV> lotList;

   String currency;
   ...
}


public class GroupingMissionMV implements Serializable {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = -343336819042189462L;

   private List<MissionMV> missionMVList;

   private int statusNiveau;

   private String statusImgColor;

   ...
}
```

I don't want to paste the code of MissionMV because it is a bit large but it has like 50 attributes and 3 quite small objects. The response on the client side has 17 kb as gzip. I heard that jackson is quite fast so I don't really understand why it is so slow. I put a logger before and after `mappr.writeValueAsString(myObject)` to be sure that this is where the problem is.

Comment: Perhaps instead of sending a giant response to one request, you could send around 200 requests and responses.  It would still take a long time, but the client could receive and display the first few responses quicker.

Answer (score 0):

This is not enough information, and specifically it is not clear that time is spent with JSON handling. You mention gzip, for example, and uncompressing gzip encoded content takes longer than parsing JSON. Are you sure time is not spent on that? It is also not clear whether you might be counting in time it takes to receive content over HTTP; or, if you have measured steady-state performance (in Java, first calls to any code is much slower than further usage).
In short, it is not clear why you think JSON parsing part is slow; nor is it possible to evaluate (content size is not mentioned).

If you wanted to know performance of JSON parsing you would have to test that by reading from in-memory (already downloaded content); or, at least buffer content from network, measuring different parts separately.